# C++ Standard for dynamic Libraries on Windows and Linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows, gcc, dynamic-library

where can i find examples of how to create one basic c++ project that uses dynamic shared libraries on windows and linux?
I need just of a simple example with one .cpp and .h file for the shared library and one for the program.

Comment: On Google. There are plenty of good hits for things like "shared library C++ example" or "shared library C++ tutorial"

Comment: >.> it's useless. All things are on google! then why ask on stackoverflow? >.>

Comment: Stack Overflow has its set of rules for determining what is on topic and what is not. Refer to the [relevant section of the site's help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), especially point 5.

Comment: And here's something to get you started: [3rd Google hit on "shared library C++ example"](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/42363-creating-shared-libraries/). [1st Google hit on "dll C++ example"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms235636.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

This is a very difficult topic. Shared libraries have very different setups and small variations among platforms.

My recommendation is that you use one tool to generate the shared library for you with the appropiate flags.

I recommend you to use one of this, and in this order, if you only want to compile for windows and linux:

1. [WAF](https://code.google.com/p/waf/)
2. [CMake](http://cmake.org)